# Angular UI router not loading child templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following the code but am still trying to get to grips with Angular UI Router. I have a parent state so that I can call a function using `resolve` and apply this to all its children. My issue is that with this code `create-prealert.html` is not appearing and `EnterDataController` is not firing.

What is happening is that both alerts are occureing and then nothing more.

I can confirm everything is fine once I remove the parent state or if I remove `parent : app,`.

Is there something fundamental behind how this works that I am missing?

I felt there was no need for other code as every thing is perfect when not attempting anything with parent states.

**EDIT:** I can also confirm it has nothing to do with `resolve` in either state. I tried it without them and still the same issue.

```
 $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                controller: 'MainController as data',
                resolve: {
                    checkAuth: ['Auth','$timeout',function(Auth, $timeout){
                        return $timeout(function(){
                                alert('This is the alert for the parent state');
                            }
                            , 500 
                        );
                    }]
                }
            })
            .state('prealert', {
                parent : 'app',
                url: '/create-prealert',
                templateUrl: 'views/create-prealert.html',
                controller: 'EnterDataController as data',
                resolve: {
                    checkAuth: ['Auth','$timeout',function(Auth, $timeout){
                        return $timeout(function(){
                                alert('This is the alert for the child state');
                            }
                            , 500 ...loading...
                        );
                    }]
                }

            })
            .state('received', {
                url: '/received',
                templateUrl: 'views/received.html',
                controller: 'EnterDataController as data'
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this, at least to the point that I understand somewhat what was happening.

I tried putting in other templates to see what would happen and realised everything was fine once it had a template to load.

I then created a parent.html file containing `<div ui-view></div>` and it worked. I can't help but think I am approaching this all wrong. But its working for me anyway.

```
       .state('app', {
            templateUrl: 'views/parent.html',
            controller: 'MainController as data',
            resolve: {
                checkAuth: ['Auth','$timeout',function(Auth, $timeout){
                    return $timeout(function(){
                            alert('This is the alert for the parent state');
                        }
                        , 500 
                    );
                }]
            }
        })
```